# How can i get the last row data in my datatable to the string

Tags: c#, datatable

I need to display the last row that i am getting in my datatable but i always get the first row into this line.Let us assume this is the image that i can see when debugging and this has 2 columns 5 rows i nee to get second column in the 5 th row

Answer (score 1):

Just change your query to

```
"select top 1 id,name from demo where id='" + id + "' order by id desc;
```

You should create an sqlParameter for the id by the way...

To be honest I don't even see the point on using a datatable for this.

You should change your code to something like this:

```
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ReferenceToYourConnectionString"].ToString()))
    {
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(ViewState["id"].ToString()); //Whatever your id columntype is
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 id,name FROM demo WHERE id = @id ORDER BY id, name DESC";
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
             CKEditor1.Text = dr["name"].ToString()
        }
    }
```

Comment: first column? or column index = 1? if you say "the first column" you get the workid is that what you want?

Comment: thats precisely why i added a comment stating that you must change that field to whatever matches your database field. So set it to **SqlDbType.Int**. And you may as well cast the viewstate to Int.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to refer to the last row of the datatable

```
string text = dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count-1][1].ToString();
```

Comment: Yes Right! But the image contains same value for all the rows. How can you say this is not the result form 5th column?